# Azure Data Factory copy activity creates empty files

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Whenever I use ADF copy activity with Blob as source/sink, ADF creates an empty file named after the directory of the sink Blob.
For instance, if I want to copy from input/file.csv to process/file.csv, the copy happens but I also have a blob called "process" with size 0 byte created each time.

Any idea why?

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vZ5w.png)
[Sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyyou.png)

Comment: Hi @Grégory Vial, can you add more info like your copy activity - source/sink settings pic.

Comment: We need to how you set the copy active, can you give any screenshots?

Comment: See edit in the question with added screenshots.

Comment: @GrégoryVial It seams that you are copying multiple.csv file into one file. I haven't met this situation, can you refresh the Data Factory and run again? Or restart the browser.

Comment: @leon Yue, this is not the case, this is one to one copy

Comment: @GrégoryVial sorry, you are using the wildcard path expresion *.csv, I miss understand. But since it's one to one, why don't set the filename directly with the parameter?

Comment: Good point I shall try putting the file name directly!

Comment: @GrégoryVial hope you're doing well. The expression *.csv is usually used for multiple files which end with .csv. Please let me know it it works. I will post it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @GrégoryVial, is the issue solved now? If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest you optimize you pipeline copy active settings.

Since you are copying one file from one container/folder to another, you can directly set the source file with parameter. Wildcard path expression *.csv is usually used for folder the same type of files.

You can test again and check if the empty file exist again.

HTH.

Comment: Using the file name instead of the wildcard solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @GrégoryVial you're welcome. can you please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have a storage ADLS gen2 but you have not enabled the Hierarchical namespace and you select the ADLS gen2 while defining your Linked Service and Dataset. A quick fix for this is use Azure Blob Storage when defining LS and DS.